# How do I add images to an aspx site based off of a list of items from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am attempting to create a store page, and for the storefront page I need to create something that will

1. list items from the database,
2. get the ID + Image URL saved in the database
3. create an hyperlinked image for each item in the query.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

The hyperlinked image will be an image of a product and links to a store page based on ID.
and a list of them will be displayed for the person to click on.

Thank you in advance, this project is a first for me (as well as my first web application in asp.net) and I'd like to see it done right!

And the site is done in C#, although if necessary I can port over to VB, at this time, not much actual code behind has been written, and I am comfortable enough with both to port whatever code I have over to it)

Comment: How have you decided to talk to the database? ADO.Net, EF, something else?

Comment: You seem to have the general idea already clear in your mind (Read data from DB -> Use URL and create <img> to display it. Enclose the Image in a <a> tag to create a link). So, can you clarify what exactly is the part you trying to get answered?

Comment: i'm unsure if about webforms or MVC, but i'm working with the empty ASP.NET website project in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Comment: @InSane... basically i understood how to do that, but wondered on how to make it create that so it makes a new hyperlinked image based on the SELECTed items from the DB.

Comment: Choosing webforms vs MVC is something that you have to choose depending on your skill level / knowledge of either. If not sure, go MVC, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use an ASP.NET repeater.

Class documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9283stf

One detailed (although potentially out-of-date) article I found with a quick search is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

(But there are plenty of other "how to use repeater control" articles out there).

Good luck.